# "Segmentation fault (core dumped)" Error while reading words from a text file and adding them to a list

Tags: c, linked-list

i have this code trying to read a word from a list of words stored in a .txt file

```
char *getWord(char *filename)  {
    char formatstr[15], *word;
    static FILE *input;
    static int firstTime = 1;
    if (firstTime) { 
        input = fopen(filename, "r");
        if (input == NULL) {
            printf("ERROR: Could not open file \"%s\"\n", filename);
            exit(1);
        }
        firstTime = 0;
    }
    word = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*WORDLEN);
    if (word == NULL) {
        printf("ERROR: Memory allocation error in getWord\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    sprintf(formatstr, "%%%ds", WORDLEN-1);
    fscanf(input, formatstr, word);
    if (feof(input)) {
        fclose(input);
        return NULL;
    }   
    return word;    
}
```

And then this code to try and store it into a linked list

```
struct num1* wdStr(int wdLength, char *filename)
{

    int d; // total words.
    char *wordC;

    struct num1 *head = NULL;
    struct num1 *temp;  

    d = edCount(filename);      

    for(int i = 0; i < d; i++) 
    {       
        wordC = getWord(filename);              

        if(strlen(wordC) == wdLength)
        {
            temp = (struct num1*)malloc(sizeof(struct num1));
                temp->val = wordC;
                temp->next = head;
                head = temp;
        }       
    }   
    //return head;
}
```

edCount just counts how many words are there.

So after running the program, always before the last word i get a "Segmentation fault (core dumped)" error. I know i am doing something wrong with the pointers but still i cant find what.

Comment: This is fairly easily solved with a debugger. Which OS are you running on?

Comment: [Please don't cast the return value of `malloc()` in C](http://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/28169).

Comment: you are returning local pointers from both of your functions. They are out of scope after returning from the function, so behaviour is undefined.

Comment: @Dipto: not a problem; the pointers are initialized via `malloc()`, so it isn't an issue.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, yes, overlooked that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> after running the program, always before the last word, I get a "Segmentation fault (core dumped)"

This is because your `getWord` returns `NULL` after the last word, but your `main` calls `strlen` on it unconditionally. This dereferences the `NULL` pointer, leading to a crash.

Note that your code produces a memory leak: your `getWord` implementation forgets to `free` the allocated `word` before returning `NULL` for the end of stream marker.

**NOTE:** Unless this is a specific learning exercise on statics, the use of `FILE *input` is highly questionable, because it makes your `getWord` non-reentrant for no good reason.

Comment: I know about the memory leak, but i just wanted to fix this issue first. 

Knowing that getWord gives NULL at eof i also tried to add this  if(wordC ==NULL)
      return head;
before if(strlen(wordC) == wdLength), but still i get the same error

Comment: @green_leaf Returning when `wordC` is `NULL` should have worked fine. The new crash is probably coming from some other place that calls your `wdStr` function.

Comment: indeed you where correct. And yes actually i have to use getWord and not alter it unfortunately, including the memory leak i suppose.

Answer (score 1):

getWord returns NULL for eof case , you dont seem to be handling it !